# How to automate the Configuring the AWS Command Line Interface and setting up profile process in python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I want to automate the Configuring the AWS Command Line Interface shown at [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html) page in python. I want to do so so that i don't have to manually type in every step (like the aws access key id,secret access key,region and output format) as I have a large number of servers that needs this step.

Is there way that I can code this in a python script and when I run that python on individual servers it will do this profile setup? With this I will only have to run a script in each server and not run run every individual step.

Answer (score 17):

helloV is helpful, should be upvoted.

Here's my re-working of it ( you may or may not need the sudo in last command )

( note this is bash, not python - many ways to pythonise the general idea :-) )

```
aws configure set default.region us-east-1
aws configure set aws_access_key_id 'YOUR_ACCESS_KEY'
aws configure set aws_secret_access_key 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY'
aws ecr get-login | sudo sh
```

And here as a one liner .

```
aws configure set default.region us-east-1; aws configure set aws_access_key_id 'YOURSACCESSKEY' ; aws configure set aws_secret_access_key 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY'; aws ecr get-login | sudo sh
```

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to add that you can apply the configuration to a profile: `aws configure set default.region us-east-1 --profile <profile-name>`
Source: [set | AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configure/set.html)

Answer (score 11):

I suggest using `Ansible` and copy the config files to servers. Easiest and error free. If `Ansible` is ruled out, call `aws configure set`

If you want to create the config file, execute the following in `subprocess`:

```
aws configure set aws_access_key_id xxxxxxxxx
aws configure set aws_secret_access_key xxxxxxxxx
....
```

If you want to set it in the Python script only, set the environment variable in the script:

```
import os
os.environ['aws_access_key_id'] = 'xxxxxxxxx'
```

Comment: the `os.environ[]` will it be setting the keys and region in aws credential and config file?

Comment: `os.environ` for that session/process only. If you want to create the files, use `aws configure set`

Comment: I am doing `result = subprocess.Popen(["aws","configure","set","aws_access_key_id", access_key_id])` but I am getting `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` even though I have aws cli installed

Comment: Try `/usr/bin/aws`

Comment: Were you able to fix errno2 above?

Comment: @helloV Which all config files will I have to copy?

Answer (score 4):

Rather than relying on the os of your servers, or any other aspect of your servers, that may lead to compatibility issues of the python script.

I suggest using the boto3 library in the python script.

Depending on which resource you want to connect in the aws service. Let's say S3.

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='xxxxxxxx',
    aws_access_key_id='xxxxxxxxx',
    aws_secret_access_key='xxxxxxxxx')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you managed to solve the issue after 4 years, but for a visitors note, this is a totally wrong approach, in this case you need to use EC2 instance profile which you can grant access to what ever AWS resources for example s3.

Answer (score -1):

And what is wrong with the bash below

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id > test.txt
ID=cat test.txt | cut -d [ -f 1]

IP="13.127.33.125"

Allow_IP=`/usr/bin/aws ec2 describe-instances --output json |grep -i PublicIp|grep $IP|head -1|awk -F":" '{print $2}'|tr -d ","|tr " \" " " "|tr -d " "`


if [ "$Allow_IP" == "" ]
then
    /usr/bin/aws ec2 associate-address --instance-id $ID --public-ip $IP
else
    echo "IP not availble " >>/var/tmp/script.out
fi
```

Comment: The question specifically asks for a way to do it using Python. Not Bash. And no subprocess with Bash is not a good answer here sincea Python SDK exists.